# Why Gorm ignore a struct when CreateTable?

Tags: go, go-gorm

#### What version of Go am I using (`go version`)?

Go version Go 1.9.1 Linux/amd64

#### Which database and its version am I using?

sqlite3

#### A complete runnable program to reproduce my issue:

Need to runnable with [GORM's docker compose config](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) or please provide your config.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

type A struct {
    ID      int
    Bs              [] *B `gorm:"foreignkey:AID"`
}

type B struct {
    ID      int
    AID     int
    Config          Config `gorm:"type:text"`
}

type Config struct {
    attr1   int
    attr2   string
}


func main() {
    Db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    Db.CreateTable(&A{})
    Db.CreateTable(&B{})
}
```

*However, the schema of test.db is*

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE "as" ("id" integer primary key autoincrement );
CREATE TABLE "bs" ("id" integer primary key autoincrement,"a_id" integer );
```

As we can see, B's `config` attribute was not created.
So Why Gorm is ignoring the `Config` struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data is not normalized. `Config` is a struct with multiple fields. You can extract config into a separate table with a foreign key, like you did with `B`:

```
type B struct {
    ID     int
    AID    int
    Config Config `gorm:"foreignkey:BID"`
}
```

And then define the foreign key in `Config`:

```
type Config struct {
    BID   int
    attr1 int
    attr2 string
}
```

At the end, you create the table:

```
Db.CreateTable(&Config{})
```

Comment: Is it means that if an attribute of a struct is not normalized and it is not intend to be a separate table, then Gorm will not take it as a column of the table?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. The question is: How should a struct with an int and a string as attributes be converted into a string and back? This is not something that gorm can guess.

Comment: Beside that. You should want to normalize your data in a relational database to remove redundancies and improve data integrity.